# Pass url from Ionic 1 app to inapp browser

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I have been working in an Ionic1 project where I get an URL from a backend API which I have to pass to a html(iframe) template and load the html template in In App browser.

I have been using `window.localStorage` to acheive this functionality and its working fine but suddenly in Inappbrowser, the local storage value is returning null.

In my app,
I am storing as `window.localStorage.setItem("urltoSend", urlvalue)` and in the controller.js i am able to get the stored value by `window.localStorage.getItem("urltoSend")`.

Now I am loading a local html(iframe) template in browser. This is the template where i have to pass the stored url to the `iframe` `src`.

In html page, When i get the stored value by `window.localStorage.getItem("urltoSend")`, Its giving me a null value.

> Note: In the controller.js, I am getting the stored value but in this external page i am not getting values.

So, how to pass the value to Inappbrowser from ionic1 app. Any ideas would be greatly helpful to gain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `window.localStorage` (or `localStorage` to be clear) because your scope had changed. The `window` of you app is not the same as the one in the inAppBrowser.

If you need to pass a value to the website/html opened in inAppBrowser then just pass an url paramenter

```
www.myExternalWebSite.com/somePath/someFile.html&thisIsMyValueKey=ThisIsMyValue
```